# For $n \geq 2$, show that $\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r \sqrt{\binom{n}{r}} < \sqrt{2 ^ {n - 1} n ^ 3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Good day,

Can someone help me with giving **hints** for this problem:

> Show that for $n \geq 2, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r \sqrt{\binom{n}{r}} < \sqrt{2 ^ {n - 1} n ^ 3}$$

I tried $$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r \sqrt{\binom{n}{r}} = \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \sqrt{r ^ 2\binom{n}{r}}$$

$$= \sqrt{n} \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \sqrt{r\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}}$$

So, we need to prove $$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \sqrt{r\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}} < n \sqrt{2 ^ {n - 1}}$$

This reminds me of $$\sum_{r = 0}^{n} (r + 1) \binom{n}{r} = n 2 ^ {n - 1} + 2 ^ n = 2 ^ {n - 1}(n + 2)$$

but I can't see how to use it.

Also, the only complex math inequality I know is AM-GM, so it's quite possible that it is my theoretical knowledge that is lacking. So, if a well-known inequality is used, please also mention it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r \sqrt{\binom{n}{r}} &\le \left(\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \binom{n}{r}\right)^{1/2} \\
&= \left((2^n-1)\left(\frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}\right)\right)^{1/2} \\
&< \left(2^{n-1}\cdot2\left(\frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}\right)\right)^{1/2}
\end{align*}
Then, verify $2\left(\frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}\right) < n^3$ for $n \ge 4$ by induction while manually checking the $n=2, n=3$ cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that we can avoid proving the last inequality, if we apply Cauchy-Schwarz  on $\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \sqrt{r\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}} < n \sqrt{2 ^ {n - 1}}$

Comment: $\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \sqrt{r\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r} \sqrt{\sum_{r = 1}^{n} \binom{n - 1}{r - 1}} < \sqrt{n ^ 2} \sqrt{2 ^ {n - 1}}$

Comment: $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} < n^2$ because $n > 1$